# Passing two lists into get requests, but it passes entire lists

Tags: python, api, python-requests

How do I call api based on two lists ? 
Have two lists, `states` and `counties`. Using these lists to call and get `some_results`. But `AK` item in `states` list doesn't have `counties` as responses so it should just skips it. But when I tried to debug it with:
 `print("requests.get('https://represent.opennorth.ca/states/{0}/counties/{1}/area_codes'.format(states, counties))")` 
I noticed that the loop inserted the entire lists instead of one by one item in the list: 
`>> requests.get('https://represent.opennorth.ca/states/[AK, GA, NY]/counties/[gwinneth, duluth, manhattan, bronx]/area_codes'` 
How do I solve this?

```
states = [AK, GA, NY]
counties = [gwinneth, duluth, manhattan, bronx]

some_results = []
for county in counties:
    rr = requests.get('https://represent.opennorth.ca/states/{0}/counties/{1}/area_codes'.format(states, counties))
    if rr.status_code == 200:
        some_results.append(rr.json())
    else: 
        print("Request to {} failed".format(states, counties))
```

Comment: depends on your business logic. you can either ignore the error ones, or filter them in input.

Comment: @LeiYang I went on and check the logic of the loop and it's inserting entire lists of states and counties. It's not looping through the list one by one as you can see in the errors I'm receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. also read the comments.

```py
import requests

# suppose these are all string variables defined elsewhere
states = [AK, GA, NY]  # why not [GA, NY]?
counties = [gwinneth, duluth, manhattan, bronx]

some_results = []
for state in states:
    for county in counties:
        # you should only pass single string here, never list
        url = f'https://represent.opennorth.ca/states/{state}/counties/{county}/area_codes'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            some_results.append(resp.json())
        else:
            print(f"Request to {state} {county} failed")
            print(resp.status_code)
            print(resp.reason)
            print(resp.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, now it seems to go through each state and county with your suggestions of that string formation. How can I add auth to this? I'm getting states from some other api calls so I have to stick with it.

Comment: it depends on the api. please only ask one thing in one question.